# Laravel command is not working - Windows 7

Tags: windows, laravel, installation

I'm trying to install laravel command installer, but its not working.

Followed link: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1

I have installed composer successfully, in fact composer command is working fine.

After installing composer, I have run this command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

as said in installation doc.

Output of above command in cmd:

Changed current directory to

> C:/Users/xXx/AppData/Roaming/Composer ./composer.json

has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
I have also set environment variables in here:

> "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment > Variables"
>
> > "Path"

.
I have set both variables User variable and System variable. Also restarted the PC.

But when I run laravel command it says:

> 'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I'm using Windows 7.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure to find the name of you PC's User. Mostly can be
   find in
   [`C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`]. Now
   this will be available once the Laravel is installed in Widows
   platform.
2. Once you confirmed its location. Go to *My Computer" > "Properties"

   > "Advanced" > "Environment > Variables > Path'*.
3. Add semi-colon make sure no space.
4. Add `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` with
       your user name. Restart command prompt, and you're good to go.

I made some detail Laravel in [Installing Laravel 5 with XAMPP or Wamp on Windows Platform](http://anytch.com/installing-laravel-5-with-xampp-or-wamp-on-windows-platform/)

Answer (score 0):

i hope your path in environment variable is wrong you have to set path till vendor/bin directory of composer global

> C:\Users\xXx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

than it will start taking all globally install packages as command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to place Composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in your `$PATH` so the laravel executable can be located by your system. This directory exists in different locations based on your operating system; however, some common locations include:

```
macOS: $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin

Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

GNU / Linux Distributions: $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin or $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

> You could also find the composer's global installation path by running
>   composer global about and looking up from the first line.

Source : [laravel-doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x)

Answer (score -3):

Did you do `composer install`? I think that's the problem.